# Google Map V3 off center in hidden div

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google map inside a div that I need to be hidden by default

```
<div id="newpost" style="display:none;">
```

When the map is unhidden a part of it isn't rendering.  I'm guessing I have to reload the map onSubmit.  Anybody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Here's my code:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#newcatchhide').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#newpost').toggle('show');
    });
});
```

This is the map oad function on the body tag:

```
<body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">
```

Here is the div that is toggled, and the div that contains the map:

```
<div id="newpost" style="display:none;">
  <div id="map" style="width: 500px; height: 300px"></div>
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Something like this? http://jsbin.com/imuri5
The idea is to initialize the map *after* displaying the DIV.

EDIT:
Ok based on your update replace:

```
jQuery('#newcatchhide').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#newpost').toggle('show');
    });
```

with:

```
var onLoad = true;
jQuery('#newcatchhide').live('click', function(event) {        
    jQuery('#newpost').toggle(function() {
        if(onLoad) {
            load();
            onLoad = false;
        }
    });
});
```

And then remove `onload="load()"` from the body tag

Comment: Yes, that looks correct.  I'm confused though - The map is initialized on the body tag:

<body onload="load()" onunload="GUnload()">

Would I close the body tag and open it again inside the div?

Comment: What do you mean by open the body tag inside the div? there should be only one body tag right after the head tag and all your DIVs inside it? what JS bit you are using to display the DIV? call that function there.

Comment: I'm using jQuery toggle on the div.  Are you saying call the onload="load()" ?

   <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('#newcatchhide').live('click', function(event) {        
         jQuery('#newpost').toggle('show');
    });
});

  </script>

Comment: I guess u meant `jQuery('#newpost').toggle('slow');` , also do you want to hide the DIV on a later stage? is this why you are using toggle? what you can do is have a global variable flag `var onLoad = true;` and then `jQuery('#newpost').toggle('slow', function() {if(onLoad) {load();onLoad = false;} });` and delete the `onload="load()"` from your body tag, this way the initialization will be called just once

Comment: Hmm..  Looks like it's still doing the same thing.  I was using the toggle.('show') parameter.  Is 'slow' a typo?  Does the jQuery you posted get added on to my existing code, with the var onLoad = true; directly before hand?

Comment: I thought your code is a typo! have a look at the [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function, there's no parameter called "show". can you explain why you are using toggle? do you want to be able to show AND hide the DIV on a later stages? and no replace your toggle function with mine and yes put that line before calling the toggle..also can you edit your question and show us your page code?

Comment: Yes, I want the user to be able to open the div, make multiple submissions (through a form post inside the div) and then close it by hitting the button again.  I will add the code to my question.  Thanks!

Comment: Showing the div first sorted it for me.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks for this. None of the other suggestions worked for me. This one works a treat!

Comment: load(); As simple as that - spent ages looking at this, thank you.

Answer (score 13):

I recently had this same issue myself and discovered the fix to be quite simple:

```
google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
```

Where `map` is your google map instance.

You can call this after you make your div visible.

If you use jQuery for the map, you can use

```
map = $('#map_canvas').gmap().map;
```

Comment: Hello Jani,

Would I call this on the toggle button submit?  Thanks!

Comment: You would call this after you have made the map visible.

Comment: Thats the proper way to do it. You may need to center the map afterwards, though..

Answer (score 0):

better:

```
gmap.redraw = function() {
    gmOnLoad = true;
    if(gmOnLoad) {
        google.maps.event.trigger(gmap, "resize");
        gmap.setCenter(gmlatlng);
        gmOnLoad = false;
    }
}
```

and in show click event:

```
$("#goo").click(function() {
  if ($("#map_canvas").css("display") == "none") {
    $("#YMapsID").toggle();
    $("#map_canvas").toggle();
    if (gmap != undefined) {
        gmap.redraw();
    }
  }
});
```